# HTML: What is the point of using an anchor as a stub within an <a> element?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an advantage to option 1 below?  I see a lot of engineers using this but I've really strictly stuck to using `<a>` tags when I am directly linking and otherwise, I'd use a `div`.

```
1//    <a href="#" onclick="doThis()>Foo</a>

2//    <div onclick="doThis()>Foo</a>
```

Comment: That is invalid markup. Don't use an `<a>` when what you want is a `<button>`.

Comment: As with all other comments and solutions - use a button when the correct semantic tool is a button. A simple guideline when to use an <a> or a button..... An <a> element changes location or context (the href attribute allows navigation to a difffernt page or to a different location in the same page). A button allows an action within the same context (updating a form element / toggling a panel etc)... so the test is... if you are remaining in the same location or context - use a button... if you are changing location or context - use an <a>  element.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can think of

Advantages when using anchor

- better keyboard (tab) navigation,
- keyboard focus indicator
- inbuilt browser appearance on hover, link, visited.
- how screen readers read the tag and contents (mainly for accessibility)

As @Brenden and @Pointy mentioned a button would be sematically correct here as you dont have a href(but I think that you might be aware and question is about difference in approach ).

If you are  using button and need the apperacne look like anchor you need to apply styles for `:hover`, `:link`, `:visited` etc.

Also if you are using `<a href="#" onclick="doThis()>Foo</a>` you need to prevent the default behavior of the anchor (eg: `event.preventDefault()`) else the page url will be be appended with `#` and page will be navigated to top.

Comment: Just to add to this, you get those exact same things using a button. Since the anchor with a meaningless href is probably not going to be used for navigation, a button might be a better choice for accessibility.

Comment: Alternatively, setting href to "javascript:void(0)" does the same as using "#", but you don't have to use `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

`<a></a>` elements are commonly used for hyperlinks with a `href` attribute to indicate their destination.
In this case, the `a` tag acts like a `button` because you only want to trigger an event, not to link from one page to another. You’re trying to double up on watching when the user clicks. Because a standard click both activates the link and triggers the `onclick` event. I personally would use `button` tag in this case.